# "Params cannot be resolved to a variable" - In android Asynctask program

Tags: android

Help me I am getting error with this line shown in picture,
How to solve this Problem in android  program  .

[image: Android error]

Comment: we cannot see your image. please update it and add some code. Add the failed part.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Metehan Toksoy , you gone through my question. I am new to stackoverflow  and i got error message while uploading image in the question- "you need at least 10 reputation to post images ".Please help me with this problem.

Comment: because your variable is called `arg0` and not `Params`...

Comment: Thank you Sir EpicPandaForce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have copied this code snippet. It cannot be resolved to a variable, because you have not declared `Params`. In your case the parameter is named `arg0`. So you have to replace `Params[0]` with `arg0[0]`! Or you simply click on **Change to 'arg0'** in the pop-up.